# generate a Django-REST-API directly ?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, models

I have already a database that contains 100 tables.

Now, I would like to expose it as a REST-API.

I've done this before so I am familiar with the procedure. 
I create a serializer for the model, a ViewSet for the Serialiizer and an a router. 
I test it on 2 tables and it works.

The problem is that I want to expose all my 100 tables. And doing the same prcedure 100 times is no fun.

Is there a way to do it only one time?

Comment: There has got to be somewhere for the system to understand what your tables' schema is. So, if you have your database schema in some industry standard formats, you might find someone's work that translates it into django serializers. Else, take it as an opportunity to contribute a schema-to-serializer translator to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is no way to do so in django.

> NOW, THIS IS NOT THE BEST SOLUTION,
>
> SOMETIMES,  DIFFERENT SERIALIZERS CLASSES ARE NEEDED DEPENDING ON RELATIONS

I just created a script that works:

You just need to run it from your project directory with your app name as an argument

```
`import os
import sys

ROUTER_TEMPLATE = "router.register(r'{}', views.{}ViewSet)"
SERIALIZER_TEMPLATE = """
class {}Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = {}
        fields = '__all__'
"""
VIEW_TEMPLATE= """

class {}ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = {}.objects.all()
    serializer_class = {}Serializer


"""

def gen_api(app_name):
        models= open(app_name+'/models.py', 'r')
    aLines = models.readlines()

    for sLine in aLines:

        aLine = sLine.split()

        for sWord in aLine:

            if sWord == "class" and aLine[aLine.index(sWord)+1] != "Meta:":
                model_name= aLine[aLine.index(sWord)+1].split("(")[0]
                gen(app_name,model_name )




def gen(app_name, name):

    config = open(app_name+'/urls.py', 'a') #append
    config.write("\n"+ ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(name, name))
    config.close()

    config = open(app_name+'/serializers.py', 'a') #append
    config.write("\n"+ SERIALIZER_TEMPLATE.format(name, name))
    config.close()

    config = open(app_name+'/views.py', 'a') #append
    config.write("\n"+ VIEW_TEMPLATE.format(name, name, name))
    config.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    gen_api(sys.argv[1])
`
```